# how to set class path for more than one jar is used in command prompt in java

Tags: java

i am developing a program,for that want to use more than one jar(Example servlet.jar and mysql.jar) i know how to import them in using Eclipse IDE. but not in cmd prompt. Can anybody help me for this thanks in advance...

Comment: Check-out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For multiple jars you can do

```
java -cp "path1/servlet.jar;path2/mysql.jar" yourPackage.Class
```

Or put all jars in one folder (let it be path1/lib) and do something like following

```
java -cp "path1/lib/*" yourPackage.Class
```

Note : classpath wildcards can be used only in Java 6 or later.

Comment: Please note that the syntax is error prone. The "path1/lib/*" will work, something like "path/lib/MySQL*" probably not. Also I mean to remember that the seperator between the JARs is platform depending (not 100% sure).

Comment: thanks for a clarification ;(semi colon) only used to seperate 2 jars, am i correct.

Comment: Nope any two path.. not just the jars. You can include two directories as well.

Comment: In similar way we can add several path seperated by ;(semi colon) in value field for the classpath variable in environmental variable also na

Comment: Yup same way in Windows. In linux I think it is `:`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new classpath, write this:

`set CLASSPATH=classpath1;`

You can see all your classpaths if you type only this:

`set`

Comment: yeppp!! thanks for the set command Jankie

Answer (score 1):

ClassPath set through command prompt will work only for current cmd window. Once you close it and open a new cmd window it will not work. Rather than setting classpath from command prompt, keep related paths to system properties:

For windows:

go to My Computer--> Properties--> Advance System Settings--> Environment Variables--> CLASSPATH--> put your path like this--> path1;path2;path3;. Don't forget to keep . (DOT) at the end.

Comment: oh thanks Shailesh, Your syntax little bit confusing me can give a example.

Comment: i understood Shailesh.. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can set your class path using cmd prompt like :-

> set classpath=(dir of classpath1);(dir of classpath2);(`dir of class
>   path3`);%CLASSPATH%

Answer (score 0):

In enviorment variables , make a new variable named classpath and in value field write as much path you want but seperate them by semicolon.